# HTML onKeyDown-Event calling function and button-click

Tags: javascript, html, input, enter, onkeydown

I'm trying to create a search option.

If someone is using my search field, they can press the "Search-Button" or just press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to start the function.

My problem is that if they press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key within the text box it starts my `function` and after the `function` it calls the `button click`.

I've used Google but couldn't solve it, even tried to disable the button while `myFunc()` is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form>Search
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="searchField" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunc()">
            <br>
            <button type="button" id="myButton" onClick="myFunc()">Search</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `myFunc()` code? The most important part of your question

Comment: @Jesse the function its self has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Alright. My mistake. I must have read it too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to stop the event propagation in this case.
I've changed your code to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  Search<br>
  <input type="text" id="searchField" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13){console.log('Hello World from Input'); return false;}">
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="myButton" onClick="console.log('Hello World from Button')">Search</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Pressing enter while the input element has the focus gives me only `Hello World from Input` at the console.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for: https://jsfiddle.net/7vf9pz8u/1/

HTML

```
<form>Search
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="searchField" onKeyDown="pressEnter()">
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="myButton" onClick="myFunc()">Search</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function pressEnter() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("working");
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like that just even if I handle it with two functions both getting called. As I used Google I saw an article which said if they use the keyDown within the textfield it clicking also the first button in the form

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `onKeyDown` separately in a `function` (`onEnter`) and use `event.preventDefault();` block the default action.

See the below code.

```js
window.onEnter = function () {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Search<br>
  <input type="text" id="searchField" onKeyDown="onEnter()">
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="myButton" onClick="myFunc()">Search</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/cvyzLdy8/

Comment: Strange your example working perfeclty as it should. Mine doesn't even just got an alert in myFunc()

Comment: but in my example I have defined `onEnter` function . do u mean that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prevent form submitting by event.preventDefault() in onkeydown function.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in chrome and firefox browser and it is working perfectly as you wish, I make some update in your code to show that it is actually working fine. Follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunc(){
    alert("Typed text.: "+document.getElementById("searchField").value) 
}
</script>
<form>
  Search<br>
  <input type="text" id="searchField" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunc()">
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="myButton" onClick="myFunc()">Search</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```